# Qual é a função do function no jQuery e qual é a maneira ou a hora certa de usar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Sempre que vou trabalhar com jQuery eu simplesmente crio:

```
$(function() {

});
```

Porque foi a primeira forma que aprendi, no começo achei que era um padrão tipo "int main()" em C, mas depois me deparei com outras formas como:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});

$(function() {

});

$j(function() {

});

function funcao(jQuery) {

}

$( document ).ready(funcao);
```

Qual a forma certa de usar? Ou qual é o momento certo de usar? Porque o JavaScript puro não precisa? Qual é a sua função?

Comment: `function () {}` é JavaScript, no caso vc quer saber a diferença de `$()` e `$.ready`, vou editar o titulo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pra ser honesto, são bem semelhantes. Quando se usa:

```
$(function() {

});
```

é um *shorthand* para:

```
$( document ).ready(funcao);
```

que programadores mais experientes usam. Quando se usa:

```
$j(function() {

});
```

na verdade é o mesmo do primeiro exemplo, exceto que o alias para o jQuery está em `$j`, talvez porque `$` esteja sendo usado, dessa forma:

```
var $ = minhaLib(); // alias para outra biblioteca qualquer
$j = jQuery.noConflict(); // alias para o jQuery
```

---

**`$(document).on( "ready", manipulador)` foi depreciado na versão 1.8 e removida na 3.0**

Isso porque ele só executaria o callback se ele fosse anexado antes que o documento estivesse pronto. Isso devido a jQuery ter alterado um pouco a forma de tratar eventos assíncronos, por [esse](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-document-ready-handlers-are-now-asynchronous) motivo.

Alguns tópicos sobre:

1. https://api.jquery.com/ready/#entry-longdesc
2. https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-on-quot-ready-quot-fn-removed

Comment: Acha válido citar que até a versão 1.8 existia a forma `$(document).on("ready", handler)`, mas que se tornou obsoleta nessa versão e foi removida do jQuery 3?

Comment: É válido @AndersonCarlosWoss! vou editar baseado na documentação.

Comment: @LucasCosta O que este código faz? $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: e porque o JavaScript puro não precisa?

Comment: É para caso esteja sendo usado `$` como variável, então para não dar conflito se utiliza `jQuery.noConflict()` @WictorChaves. Editei a resposta com um exemplo.

Answer (score 6):

```
$(function() { ... });
```

é apenas uma maneira mais curta de escrever

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

ambas serão executadas quando sua DOM estiver pronta para uso. 

Veja este trecho de código:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

é a mesma coisa que:

```
function funcao(){ ... }
$(document).ready(funcao);
```

A diferença, é que no primeiro a função é anônima, e portanto existirá só ali no `$(document).ready`, na segunda, a função `funcao` existe globalmente. Ambas definem um handler para o evento de `ready` do `document`

```
$j(function() {

});
```

$j aqui, é, provavelmente, apenas um alias para o objeto `jQuery`, ou `$`, que alguém criou.

Funções são a mesma coisa em qualquer linguagem, um bloco de código que faz algo. O que muda é apenas a sintaxe.

O `jQuery` existe para nos trazer algumas ferramentas para facilitar o trabalho com JavaScript. Mas tudo que é feito com jQuery pode ser feito apenas com JavaScript puro.

Comment: Porque o JavaScript puro não precisa?

Comment: Do $? Se for, é porque o ```$``` é o álias do plugin do ```jQuery```, que é uma biblioteca